# Finding general equation for motion of a radioactive particle performing SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, differential-equations, radioactivity

Let us assume we have a particle of initial mass $m_{0}$ such that a general time $t$:

$$ m(t) = m_{0} e^{- \lambda t} $$

Now, let us say this particle is attached to a spring of spring constant $k$, such that if at a general time $t$ where the particle has moved a distance $x$ from the mean position:

$$ m(t) * a = - k x(t) $$

Where $a$ is the acceleration of the particle and is $ d^2 x(t) / dt^2 $

The initial conditions are $ x(0) = x_{0} $ and $ \frac{d}{dt} x(0) = 0 $

I have tried to solve this differential equation by taking the Laplace transform on both sides but I run into an issue where I have to relate the Laplace transform as a function of $s$ and $s+\lambda$.

If someone could provide some insight into how to solve this differential equation, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The solution involves Bessel functions, so for me that means looking up the solution in a table somewhere or using Mathematica/Wolfram.

Comment: Individual particles do not reduce in mass in this way.  They either decay or don't decay and either have their mass or it is converted to energy and the mass and kinetic energy of decay products.

Comment: @StephenG Fair point, but the "particle" could be a solid that decays to a gas, eg Ra-226 to Rn-222.

Comment: It's somewhat apart from your maths issue, but if you decay to a "gas", the gas is still trapped inside a metallic solid structure - it doesn't go anywhere except at the surface where it may escape.  A decayed daughter atom is still inside the structure its parent was in.

Answer (score 1):

Using units where $m_0$, $\lambda$, and $k$ are all $1$, change the independent variable from $t$ to $s=2e^{t/2}$. You'll get a [Bessel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) with index $0$. The solution is an appropriate linear combination of $J_0(s)$ and $Y_0(s)$. The solution as a function of $t$ looks like this:

[image]

To motivate this change of variables, the first one to try would be $s=e^t$ because this would make the mass constant in the new “time”. You’ll get something close to a Bessel equation. Then you fiddle with variants like $s=ae^{bt}$ to get it to match exactly.